# Starting GDB with interpreter mi via .gdbinit file

Tags: matlab, debugging, gdb, emacs24

I'm trying to debug a MATLAB mex function by launching gdb by 
`matlab -Dgdb`. I use emacs to interface with gdb and Matlab shells.

I need the mi interpreter for debugging to work in emacs24, which, as far as I know, cannot be specified when launching gdb by the command `matlab -Dgdb`. How do you start gdb with the mi interpreter via .gdbinit? I tried several obvious options.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to write a wrapper script that invokes `gdb` as you like, then arrange to have matlab use that script.